# Possible clutch disengagement problem causing lingering reving when clutch pedal pressed on Renault Master diesel 2006

Tags: clutch, rpm, renault

Can I ask a question about my clutch on my diesel Renault van?
My clutch stopped working; A garage fitted a new clutch kit (including master cylinder); now, when I push the clutch pedal down, the engine's revs continue for quite a few seconds, without the acceleration pedal pressed; sometimes, the revs even go up slightly. There can be a shudder, or jerk, when engaging into the next gear.
It was not like this before the clutch broke.
Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure directly what's going on. You should take it back to the shop which did the work and tell them to get it right. Sounds like they've not fitted something correctly or there's some other problem which was caused from their work.

Comment: Done so. Their going to look at it. But it's a big incovenience to have to take the vehicle there again, leave it behind, take a bus back home, and stay housebound for another week, when I've got so much to do!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the engagement point of the clutch could be too low.  This can usually be adjusted.

If this is the issue, the clutch is not actually disengaging the engine until the pedal is almost completely on the floor.  Then when letting out on the clutch, it will engage extremely quickly/jerkily.

Another potential cause of the shudder/jerk when engaging the clutch is that the flywheel was not resurfaced.  If the old flywheel was reused without resurfacing, it may have high spots that result in shudders/jerks with the new clutch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With your words in mind, I test drove it, and made sure I pressed the clutch down as fast as I could to the floor, to see if the revs stopped. No difference. Carried on reving. Now I'm noticing that if I rev in neutral, with the clutch pedal down to the floor, it sometimes carries on revving after taking foot off accelerator, and, there is a rattle, or grinding sound.

Comment: Sorry none of those ideas helped!  That is a really weird issue!

Answer (score 0):

Took van back to garage; Tested it and confirmed there is a problem with revs carrying on after clutch disengaged; Put electronic device on car, but said it would not connect. So I have to take it back on friday when the electrician is in.
Said he was convinced that it is the "throttle" out of alinement (the two tracks). Implied that I may need a new throttle, but there was absolutely no problem with it before the clutch work.
Does anyone know what is wrong? Any fix/test I can do?

Comment: I've noticed by watching the rev count carefully, that the revs are in fact increasing when the clutch is disengaged. Not just carrying on. Like a surge of electricity. ? The question is what does the mechanic who fits a clutch touch, or adjust, during his job that would cause this?